# ../ For Parent Directory Not Working HTML

Tags: html, svg, src

All,

I did a bit of research but haven't found an exact thread or resolution to this issue.

I am using express in this webapp, Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113, and Win 10 Version 1703.

I am currently developing a site where I want to use a hamburger svg for mobile navigation. This is how the html sits for the "topbar"

```
<div id="topbar">
   <img src="../images/hamburger.svg" alt="ham">
</div>
```

And here is the file structure:

https://puu.sh/xxDih/c842297b54.png

According to the structure, I should only need to do `../images/hamburger.svg`, but when I do that, it comes up with a 404 error in the waterfall. I have run into this issue multiple times doing any sort of HTML sourcing into parent directories, but in JS files it works fine.

I'm not exactly sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this is an issue with express itself.

If (in this case) you have your `index.html` as `express.static('./pages')`, then it can't see anything above pages and considers pages as the working directory.

Me, coming from React (which stupidly was the first thing I learned even before basic JS), wants to put all the pages in one folder, which I think would make sense.

The workaround I did, which may not be optimal, was by putting `index.html` as a sibling to `pages`, `css`, and `images` in the `src` folder. Then in `index.html`, it has a meta tag as follows: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=./pages/home.html" />` to redirect to the `home.html` page.

Again, this may not be optimal, but for a kinda OCD guy like myself this makes sense.

**Update:**

What we ended up doing is to have index.html be a static page, and then load the individual pages in an iframe. This website is mainly for information and has no database (yet), so there won't be much to process. Here's the new file structure that works.

http://puu.sh/xy5Dw/4dbc72ec06.png

`src` is now our working directory (`express.static('./src')`) and everything is detailed within there.

Once we do include a database, it will at most be 10 values in the server and will be using very basic requests, nothing crasy.

Answer (score 0):

For the express server，every uri are processed by the express contains resource url and request url.

- Request url(api) is refered to your express api config
- resource(image, js, css, html...) is relative to your static server's root directory which was defined by using `express.static(root_path)`.

That's what I want to say.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that images folder, node_modules folder, and pages folder are all in the same directory, and css is under the pages folder.

"../images/hamburger.svg" is the correct relative path from the pages folder, but being (big red flag) the node_modules is at "../node_modules/" I'm thinking that the server is serving from /pages/ folder, the servers root directory. meaning anything above the /pages/ folder will not be shared.

Clearly you do not want to share out ../../../windows/system32/ or the user documents etc. To prevent sharing those the highest directory you can access from the html page through a browser is the server folder being used. I'm thinking /pages/home.html is localhost/home.html and localhost/css/ is your css directory.

Programs running on the server can access files above the served directory, but the browser can not. "/node_modules/" should be outside of the servers root directory.